# Least squares solutions and orthogonal projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, orthogonality, least-squares, orthogonal-matrices

I found the least squares solution for the following inconsistent system of equations:

$ x_1 - x_2 = 0$

$ x_1 + x_2 = 5 $

$-x_1 + x_2 = 2$
, which turned out to be $
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$.

The next part of this question asks me to use this result to find the orthogonal projection of the vector $
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
5\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$ on the span of the vectors $
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
-1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$ and $
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$.

To do this, is it simply the following calculation?

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1\\
1&1\\
-1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$ $
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$? When I do this, I get $
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
5\\
-1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$. Is this the correct answer?

Comment: I presume you meant $(2,3)^T$ in the last line?

Answer (score 1):

Note that ${\cal R} A = \operatorname{sp} \{ (1,1,-1)^T , (-1,1,1)^T \}$.

The least squares solution $\hat{x}$ minimises $\|Ax-b\|^2$.

In particular, the point $A \hat{x}$ is the closest point to $b$ in ${\cal R} A$, so we have $(A \hat{x} -b) \bot {\cal R}A$, that is,
$A \hat{x}$ is the orthogonal projection of $b$ onto ${\cal R} A$.

Computing gives $A {\hat{x}} = (-1,5,1)^T$.

It is straightforward to check that $A^T (A \hat{x} -b) = 0$.